# Protecting static content with forms authentication under IIS8

Tags: iis, asp.net

I've got an ASP.NET (.Net 4) site hosted on an IIS8 (Windows 2012) server, with forms authentication in place. Everything's working fine.

I'd now like to introduce some static content - HTML "help files" - but I don't want these to be "deep linkable"; in other words, the pages should only be available when the user is authentication.

Having Google'd around, I've found a few references on how to achieve this. So in my web.config, I have (removed all the uninteresting stuff):

```
<compilation>
 <buildProviders>
    <add extension=".html" type="System.Web.Compilation.PageBuildProvider" />
    <add extension=".htm" type="System.Web.Compilation.PageBuildProvider" />
 </buildProviders>
</compilation>
```

and

```
 <handlers> 
      <add name="WebServiceHandlerFactory-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*.asmx,*.html" verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="WebServiceHandlerFactory-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*.asmx,*.html" verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />
 </handlers>
```

... but I can still access the HTML files when not authenticated.

Can anyone suggest what's wrong, and how I can protect the static HTML content?

Comment: Have you taken a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3589020/how-to-do-forms-authentication-on-purely-html-pages-using-asp-net yet?

Comment: Yes: the config I'm using is the same as the first answer on that question. But it doesn't work; I'm not sure if there's something more that's required for IIS8?

Comment: @KenD have you checked on that [http://www.iis.net/learn/application-frameworks/building-and-running-aspnet-applications/how-to-take-advantage-of-the-iis-integrated-pipeline](http://www.iis.net/learn/application-frameworks/building-and-running-aspnet-applications/how-to-take-advantage-of-the-iis-integrated-pipeline)

Answer (score 4):

[Ensure that IIS is running in **Integrated Mode**](http://www.iis.net/learn/application-frameworks/building-and-running-aspnet-applications/aspnet-integration-with-iis) in order for the following to work.

The below is an entire `Web.config` file which you could place in a sub-folder, and assumes that authentication (e.g. Forms Authentication) has been setup.
Or, extract the *authorization* and *handlers* parts, and add it to your root `Web.config`.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?" />
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="HTML" path="*.html" verb="GET, HEAD, POST, DEBUG" type="System.Web.StaticFileHandler" />
      <add name="CSS" path="*.css" verb="GET, HEAD, POST, DEBUG" type="System.Web.StaticFileHandler" />
      <add name="JS" path="*.js" verb="GET, HEAD, POST, DEBUG" type="System.Web.StaticFileHandler" />
      <add name="PNG" path="*.png" verb="GET, HEAD, POST, DEBUG" type="System.Web.StaticFileHandler" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the Location tag and whitelist the entire folder.

```
<location path="YourFiles">
    <system.web>
    <authorization>
        <allow users="?" />
    </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried Handlers?

Place this in your Web.Config file and see if it helps.

P.S. Not tested.

Comment: <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="HTML" path="*.html" verb="GET, HEAD, POST, DEBUG" type="System.Web.StaticFileHandler" />
      <add name="CSS" path="*.css" verb="GET, HEAD, POST, DEBUG" type="System.Web.StaticFileHandler" />
      <add name="JS" path="*.js" verb="GET, HEAD, POST, DEBUG" type="System.Web.StaticFileHandler" />
      <add name="PNG" path="*.png" verb="GET, HEAD, POST, DEBUG" type="System.Web.StaticFileHandler" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>

Comment: Please *edit* this comment into your answer and use the formatting tools to make it legible.